# Is it mandatory to close transaction each time in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, transactions

In Hibernate we close Session each time but is it necessary to close transaction each time in Hibernate or only transaction commit is sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can only `begin` , `commit` or `rollback` a transaction . So , `closing` a transaction  is ambiguous to me . Does it mean commit or rollback a transaction ?

If a transaction begins , a database connection will be established between the client and server . This connection will only be released if the transaction is committed , roll-backed or  time-out (if database supports it) .

Calling `session.close()` will call [java.sql.Connection#close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close%28%29) . According to the JDBC specification , if [java.sql.Connection#close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close%28%29) is called and there is an active transaction, the result of this active transaction depends on the JDBC vendor 's implementation.  In case of Postgresql, it will automatically rollback . So it is strongly recommended that an application explicitly  commits or rolls back an active transaction prior to `session.close()`